# How to make screen sessions on Cygwin persist across reboot on Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, screen

Lately I've been using screen utility a lot on my Windows 10 PC via Cygwin. I usually open 5-6 screen sessions and do my work. Every time I reboot my system and start screen, it says my old screen sessions are dead and need to be wiped out before starting a new one. I'm wondering, is there a way we can make the sessions persist after reboot and I can do something like 'screen -x' and taken back to my old set of screen sessions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a different tool https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_(software)

Comment: You cannot do that with one machine. When people do this, the screen on the local (rebooted machine) is a client to display remote sessions on one or more other machines, none of which are not rebooted.